# How to store values even after the application restarts?

Tags: database, applescript-objc

When creating applications with ApplescriptObjC you can create a property like this:

```
property myValue : "value"
```

However, if I change the value of this variable, it will get set back to "value" whenever the application restarts. How can I store values so they do not get reset after the application restarts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to store your value somewhere before your application quits. Using NSUserDefaults is the best approach:

```
property NSUserDefaults : ((current application)'s NSUserDefaults's standardUserDefaults)
```

To save your value, use the following code, where **myKey** can be any string, and **val** is the value that you want to save:

```
NSUserDefaults's setObject:val forKey:myKey
```

To retrieve your value later on, you can use:

```
NSUserDefaults's objectForKey:myKey
```

*By the way, NSUserDefaults has several useful functions for getting values, depending on the type of data stored. For example, if you were storing a boolean, you could use "boolForKey:"*.

However, you should set a default value for your key, in case it has never been saved before. This must be done before trying to retrieve the value for your key, where **defVal** is the default value:

```
NSUserDefaults's registerDefaults:((current application)'s NSDictionary's dictionaryWithObject:defVal forKey:myKey)
```

If you'd like to know more about NSUserDefaults, you can read about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/